# How do I hold a collection of one struct in another where lifetimes are not predictable?

Tags: rust

I want to manage a collection of objects in another object but I can't predict the lifetime of the elements in this collection.

I found this example in [Syntax of Rust lifetime specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705277/syntax-of-rust-lifetime-specifier/26705327#26705327) that demonstrates what I can't do:

```
struct User<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

// ... impls omitted

struct ChatRoom<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    users: HashMap<&'a str, User<'a>>,
}
```

`ChatRoom` holds a map of `User`s. Each `User` is a copy although the name within `User` is a shared reference. The `User` and the `ChatRoom` have an explicit lifetime so when they are joined the compiler enforces that `User`s must live longer than the `ChatRoom` they're going into.

But what if my `User` was created after the `ChatRoom`? I can't use lifetimes because the compiler will complain. What if I delete a `User` before the `ChatRoom`? I can't do that either.

How can the `ChatRoom` hold `User`s who might be created after it or destroyed before it? I vaguely suspect that something could be done with boxes to implement this but Rust's box documentation is quite poor so I am not certain.

Comment: No because I don't want to clone state information in this object. Think of User above - the name is a reference. In my case I have fields which can change inside my User so I don't want multiple copies floating around where the info gets stale. I could of course hold some kind of token / id to the user in the map and look it up when I need to but I'd rather just have a straight reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, some types come in pairs: a *borrowed* and an *owned* counterpart. For strings, the borrowed version is [`&'a str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html) and the owned version is [`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html). Owned versions don't have a lifetime parameter, because they **own** all their data. That doesn't mean they don't contain pointers internally; `String` stores its data on the heap, and the actual `String` object only contains a pointer to that data.

By using `String` instead of `&'a str`, you can avoid issues with the order of construction, because you can [move](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html#move-semantics) owned data around freely (so long as it isn't borrowed elsewhere). For example, when you create a `User`, you first need to create a `String`, which you would then move into the new `User`, and finally you then move the `User` into the `ChatRoom`'s `HashMap`.

```
struct User {
    name: String,
}

struct ChatRoom {
    name: String,
    users: HashMap<String, User>,
}
```

---

However, since you need shared references, then you need to wrap the `String` in a type that provides that functionality. If you are writing a single-threaded program, you may use [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) for this. If you need to access these references from multiple threads, then `Rc` won't work; you need [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) instead.

```
struct User {
    name: Rc<String>,
}

struct ChatRoom {
    name: String,
    users: HashMap<String, User>,
}
```

In order to create a new `Rc<String>` that points to the same string, you simply call the [`clone()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) method on the first `Rc<String>`.

---

Now, the `String` in an `Rc<String>` is immutable, because `Rc` doesn't provide any way to mutate its value (without consuming the `Rc`). If you need that capability, then you need to pair this with [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) (or either [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) in a multi-threaded program).

```
struct User {
    name: Rc<RefCell<String>>,
}

struct ChatRoom {
    name: String,
    users: HashMap<String, User>,
}
```